# spring boot PAYTM API integration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, paytm

can you tell me how to integrate `paytm` API in spring boot and how to add `paytm` checksum in `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to read paytm's api documentation and then u can use these to consume the restful web service of paytm , just make your own classes for receiving and sending objects to the service:

[Consuming restful web services in spring boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/)

by the way if you dont like making classes u can just retrieve the response in the form of String.class and just parse them with a json parser lib

Comment: Actual PayTm is provide jar file so How can i used that jar in our spring boot application any example share with me